# Generating dummy Boolean values for multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on data science project and  have 4 columns 10_miles, 20_miles, 30_miles, out_of_state. And want to generate dummy data with T/F values to be filled in those columns. I want only 1 True and other 3 false in one instance. For E.g

[image: Data Example]

Comment: Hi @Kash, welcome to SO! If you could provide the code you've tried already, and include your data example as code rather than an image, you'd be more likely to get help (and less likely to be downvoted). You can read more about providing a [mcve] here!

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback. Will try to do it next time.

Comment: Not following suggestions is going to mean your experience here at SO will be less rewarding.  If it's bad enough, there may not be a next time.  There's absolutely no reason you couldn't edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create a random square DataFrame where there is only a single True per row/column?

You can use numpy smart indexing for that:

```
n = 4
a = np.full((n,n), False)

# create and shuffle indexer
x = np.arange(n)
y = np.arange(n)

np.random.shuffle(x)
np.random.shuffle(y)

# assign a single True
a[x, y] = True

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['10_miles', '20_miles', '30_miles', 'out_of_state'])
```

output:

```
   10_miles  20_miles  30_miles  out_of_state
0     False     False      True         False
1      True     False     False         False
2     False      True     False         False
3     False     False     False          True
```